# Code doesn't stop running - how to fix Part::partw?

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation

I have this code divided into two notebooks, the first notebook is running just fine, and It gives some information that the second notebook uses, like some variables. The second notebook exhibits the problem - it just won't run. I have used this same code before and it used to run just fine and I didn't change it, I'm 100% sure. I used to have some problems connecting the kernel in a way that the second notebook would recognize the information from the first notebook, but that was it. Now I only get the following message and it keeps running forever.

Part::partw: Part 1003 of {0.0493827161,0.0493827161,0.0493827161,0.0493827161,0.0493827161,<<42>>,0.0493827161,0.0493827161,0.0493827161,<<951>>} does not exist.

Part::partw: Part 1003 of {0.04938271610,0.04938271610,0.04938271610,0.04938271610,0.04938271610,0.04938271610,<<39>>,0.04938271610,0.04938271610,0.04938271610,0.04938271610,0.04938271610,<<951>>} does not exist.

Part::partw: Part 1002 of {0.0493827161,0.0493827161,0.0493827161,0.0493827161,0.0493827161,<<42>>,0.0493827161,0.0493827161,0.0493827161,<<951>>} does not exist.

General::stop: Further output of Part::partw will be suppressed during this calculation.

Here is the full code:

**first notebook**

```
In[1]:= ClearAll["Global`*"]; 
Mp=250;
M=1;l=1;
g=SetPrecision[(1-(2M)/r),Mp];
hor=2M;

In[6]:= tar=SetPrecision[r+2M*Log[r-2M],Mp];
tor[r_]=tar;

In[8]:= Plot[tar,{r,1.1hor,10hor}]

Out[8]= (*graph*)

In[9]:= exp=Mp-10;
h=1/10;(*grid*)
ts=-50;
te=-ts;(*grid*)
min=tor[hor+10^-exp]
bbbw=2*10^5;
tor[bbbw]
max=bbbw;

Out[13]= -1103.240844637
Out[15]= 200024.41212529096034679234271208309299520930484729764315890347709196444741065132439151059896521735010312008709245543550934051834294272217119847031155270134026970970022481705169100906940486272200574564822514365453234079775957752387593684152687558809961862

In[17]:= NRootFinder[Function_,{var_,neg_,pos_},precision_]:=Module[{oldm=neg,n=neg,p=pos,m=(neg+pos)/2,f,g=10^(-precision)},
While[Abs[n-p]>g&&oldm!=m,
oldm=m;
f=Re[Function/.var->m];
If[f>0,p=m,If[f<0,n=m,Break[]]];
m=(n+p)/2; 
];
{var->m}];

In[18]:= xx[r_]=tar;

In[19]:= Timing[tort=Table[SetPrecision[r/. NRootFinder[xx[r]-test,{r,SetPrecision[hor+10^-exp,Mp],SetPrecision[max,Mp]},Mp],Mp],{test,ts,te,h}]; ]

Out[19]= {57.0271,Null}

In[20]:= ListPlot[tort]
Out[20]= (*graph*)
```

**second notebook**

```
In[39]:= V[r_]=-g(D[g,r]/r-(l(l+1))/r^2);
In[40]:= P=Table[V[tort[[i]]],{i,1,(2*te)/h+1,1}];
ListPlot[P,PlotRange->{-0.01,0.01}]
Out[41]= 
In[42]:= Profile[x_]=N[Exp[-x^2],Mp];
s=Table[Profile[x],{x,ts,te,h}];
s0=Profile[(ts+te)/2];
Fd=Table[0,{i,0,2te,h}];
LFd=Table[0,{i,0,2te,h}];
In[47]:= t=0; 

In[48]:= Length[P]
Out[48]= 1001
In[49]:= kpp=0;
seg=Length[s]/10;
In[51]:= Timing[len=Length[P];ar=h*h/2;For[i=Length[s],i-->2,Sp=s[[1]];s[[1]]=SetPrecision[s[[1]]-ar*(P[[1+i]]s0
+P[[3+i]]s[[1]]),Mp];For[j=1,j++<Length[s]-1,tmp=s[[j]];s[[j]]=SetPrecision[s[[j-1]]+s[[j]]-Sp-ar*(P[[j+i]]s[[j-1]]+P[[j+2+i]]s[[j]]),Mp];Sp=tmp;];t=t+2*h;If[j==i+2;Fd[[j-1]]=s[[j]];LFd[[j-1]]=Log[s[[j]]^2]/2,kpp=kpp+1];]]
During evaluation of In[51]:= DynamicPart::partw: Part 1003 of {6.386361285030213167287043342733225739218266762416365330367665924852801536385569082433956136029161340720406911615723913077392291730895261432924829676666355765166442710864823338973244719310742043040421712721239087152353953081780950379004331*10^-13,<<49>>,<<951>>} does not exist.
During evaluation of In[51]:= DynamicPart::partw: Part 1002 of {6.386361285030213167287043342733225739218266762416365330367665924852801536385569082433956136029161340720406911615723913077392291730895261432924829676666355765166442710864823338973244719310742043040421712721239087152353953081780950379004331*10^-13,<<49>>,<<951>>} does not exist.
During evaluation of In[51]:= DynamicPart::partw: Part 1004 of {6.386361285030213167287043342733225739218266762416365330367665924852801536385569082433956136029161340720406911615723913077392291730895261432924829676666355765166442710864823338973244719310742043040421712721239087152353953081780950379004331*10^-13,<<49>>,<<951>>} does not exist.
During evaluation of In[51]:= DynamicGeneral::stop: Further output of Part::partw will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

Comment: can't run your code since your variables not defined. **It used to run normally, and I didnt change the code**  Well, you must have changed something!  Did you try from clean kernel? Also try to avoid using `For` in Mathematica, it is not needed. You can use `Do` instead.  When you get this error it means your index you are using to access the list is wrong. i.e. you are going over the edge.

Comment: @Nasser i have updated the post with the complete information.

Comment: If I count the items in your list, it seems that your lists contain 1001 items but you are trying to access the 1003rd, which of course fails. I think something is wrong with the code, potentially as simple as an index running out of bounds in a loop.

Answer (score 4):

Using the notebook debugger, and inserting some Print statements, I was able to determine that your problem originates in this For loop:

```
For[i = Length[s], i-- > 2, Sp = s[[1]]; 
   s[[1]] = 
    SetPrecision[s[[1]] - ar*(P[[1 + i]] s0 + P[[3 + i]] s[[1]]), Mp]
   ]];
```

The debugger defaults to breaking on a Message. The evaluation stack indicates the message was issued after attempting to evaluate P[[3+i]].

Putting
Print[{Length[s],Length[P]}]
just before the loop returns {1001,1001}.

The problem occurs on the first iteration. You're starting from i=1001. Putting i-- into the second argument and testing for exit means you decrement i and evaluate the body with i=1000. So on the first iteration, P[[3+i]] = P[[3 + 1000]], which exceeds the length of P, which has only 1001 elements.

Since you're not evaluating to a numerical result, this is the likely cause of the code running "forever". You build up a large symbolic result, repeatedly issuing the (suppressed) message until you decide to abort.